# How to manually reproject from a specific projection to lat/lon

Tags: python, mapping, projection

I have an array from Euro-Cordex data which has a rotated pole projection from a Netcdf file:

```
grid_mapping_name: rotated_latitude_longitude
                  grid_north_pole_latitude: 39.25
                  grid_north_pole_longitude: -162.0

          float64 rlon(rlon)
              standard_name: grid_longitude
              long_name: longitude in rotated pole grid
              units: degrees
              axis: X
          unlimited dimensions: 
          current shape = (424,)
          filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used),
         ('rlat', <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
          float64 rlat(rlat)
              standard_name: grid_latitude
              long_name: latitude in rotated pole grid
              units: degrees
              axis: Y
          unlimited dimensions: 
          current shape = (412,)
```

The dimensions are rlon (424) and rlat (412). I used some codes to convert these rotated lat lons into normal lat/lons. Now, I have two matrices with shape of (424, 412). The first one shows the longitude coordinates, and the second one shows the latitude coordinates.

Now, I want to convert the initial image (424, 412) to a image with the extents that I want:Min lon : 25, Max lon: 45, Min Lat: 35, Max lat: 43

```
lats = np.empty((len(rlat), len(rlon)))
lons = np.empty((len(rlat), len(rlon)))

for j in range (len(rlon)):
    for i in range(len(rlat)):
        lons[i, j] = unrot_lon(rlat[i],rlon[j],39.25,-162.0)
        lats[i, j] = unrot_lat(rlat[i],rlon[j],39.25,-162.0)

a = lons<=45
aa = lons>=25
aaa = a*aa

b = lats<=43
bb = lats>=35
bbb = b*bb

c = bbb*aaa
```

The last matrix (c) is a boolean matrix which shows the pixels that I am interested according to the extents that I defined:

[image: The original image]
[image: Boolean matrix with defined boudries]

Now, I want to do two things that I fail in both:

First I would like to plot this image with the boundries on a basemap. For that I located the llcrnlon, llcrnlat, urcrnlon and urcrnlon based on the boolean matrix and by using some imagination:

```
llcrlon = 25.02#ok
llcrlat = np.nanmin(lats[c])# ok
urcrlon = np.nanmax(lons[c])#ok
urcrlat = np.nanmax(lats[np.where(lons==urcrlon)])#ok
```

Then I used the following codes to plot the image on a basemap:

```
lonss = np.linspace(np.min(lons[c]), np.max(lons[c]), (424-306+1))
latss = np.linspace(np.min(lats[c]), np.max(lats[c]), (170-73+1))
pl.figure(dpi = 250)
map = Basemap(projection='rotpole',llcrnrlon=llcrlon,llcrnrlat=llcrlat,urcrnrlon=urcrlon,urcrnrlat=urcrlat,resolution='i', o_lat_p = 39.25, o_lon_p =-162., lon_0=35, lat_0=45) 
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
parallels = np.arange(35,43,2.) # 
meridians = np.arange(25,45,2.) # 
map.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
map.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lonss, latss)
x, y = map(lons, lats)
mapp = map.pcolormesh(x,y,WTD[73:170, 306:])
```

[image: Here is what I get!]

So, the map is not well-fit to the basemap projection. I would like to find out what is wrong.

Second, I would like to reproject this map to normal lat/lon. For that, I use the following codes to define a new grid:

```
targ_lons = np.linspace(25, 45, 170)
targ_lats = np.linspace(43, 35, 70)
T_Map = np.empty((len(targ_lats), len(targ_lons)))
T_Map[:] = np.nan
```

Then, I am trying to figure out the differences between the lon/lat matrices I produced in the beginning and my newly defined grids. Then, using the indices which represent the minimum/less than a specific threshold, fill in the new gridded image.

```
for i in range(len(targ_lons)):
    for j in range(len(targ_lats)):

        lon_extr = np.where(abs(lons-targ_lons[i])<0.01)
        lat_extr = np.where(abs(lats-targ_lats[j])<0.01)
```

So here, if we have i=0 and j=0,

then:

```
lon_extr = (array([  7,  16,  25,  34,  35,  43,  44,  53,  63,  72,  73,  82,  83, 92,  93, 102, 103, 112, 113, 122, 123, 133, 143, 153, 154, 164,
        174, 175, 185, 195, 196, 206, 217, 227, 238, 248, 259, 269, 280,
        290, 300, 321, 331, 341, 360, 370, 389], dtype=int64),
 array([320, 319, 318, 317, 317, 316, 316, 315, 314, 313, 313, 312, 312,
        311, 311, 310, 310, 309, 309, 308, 308, 307, 306, 305, 305, 304,
        303, 303, 302, 301, 301, 300, 299, 298, 297, 296, 295, 294, 293,
        292, 291, 289, 288, 287, 285, 284, 282], dtype=int64))
```

and

```
lat_extr=(array([143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143,
        143, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145,
        145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147, 147, 148, 148, 149, 149, 150,
        150, 151, 151, 152, 152, 153, 153, 154, 154, 155, 156, 156, 157,
        157, 158, 158, 159, 159, 160, 160, 161, 162, 162, 163, 164, 164,
        165, 167, 168, 168, 169, 169, 170, 170, 171, 174, 175, 177, 178,
        180, 181, 183, 186, 190, 191, 192, 204, 205, 210, 214], dtype=int64),
 array([251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263,
        264, 265, 266, 267, 227, 228, 229, 289, 290, 291, 214, 215, 303,
        304, 204, 205, 313, 314, 196, 321, 322, 189, 329, 182, 336, 176,
        342, 170, 348, 165, 353, 160, 358, 155, 363, 150, 146, 372, 142,
        376, 138, 380, 134, 384, 130, 388, 126, 123, 395, 119, 116, 402,
        405, 106, 103, 415, 100, 418,  97, 421,  94,  86,  83,  78,  75,
         70,  68,  63,  56,  47,  45,  43,  19,  17,   8,   1], dtype=int64))
```

Now, I need to be able to pull the common coordinates and fill in the T_Map. I'm confused at this point. Is there a function for easy way to pull out the common lat/lon from these two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved. I used the Longitude and Latitude matrices to find the nearest pixels (less than the resolution which is 0.11 degree for this case) and fill up the new defined grid. Hope this helps others who have a similar problem:

```
#(45-25)*111/12.5
#(43-35)*110/12.5
targ_lons = np.linspace(25, 45, 170)
targ_lats = np.linspace(43, 35, 70)
T_Map = np.empty((len(targ_lats), len(targ_lons)))
T_Map[:] = np.nan

for i in range(len(targ_lons)):
    for j in range(len(targ_lats)):
        lon_extr = np.where(abs(lons-targ_lons[i])<0.1)
        lat_extr = np.where(abs(lats[lon_extr]-targ_lats[j])<0.1)
        if len(lat_extr[0])>0:
            point_to_extract = np.where(lats == lats[lon_extr][lat_extr][0])
            T_Map[j, i] = (WTD[point_to_extract])
```

[image]